# Map all tags of a tagged union type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, union-types

Is it possible to map all tags of a tagged union type into an array? Let's say we have the following types:

```
type Options = Cash | PayPal | CreditCard;    

interface Cash {
  kind: "cash";
}

interface PayPal {
  kind: "paypal";
  email: string;
}

interface CreditCard {
  kind: "credit";
  cardNumber: string;
  securityCode: string;
}
```

Is it possible to collect all discriminators `kind` into a string array? The result should be something like `['cash', 'paypal', 'credit']`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to get values from a type in standard typescript (there might be some unofficial extensions to the language that allow this)

You can get a type that is a union of all `kind`s:

```
type OptionsKind = Options['kind'] //  "cash" | "paypal" | "credit"
```

You can also build an object that MUST have all properties of the union and use `Object.keys` to get an array from this object:

```
type OptionsKind = Options['kind'] //  "cash" | "paypal" | "credit"
let OptionsKind: { [P in OptionsKind]: 1 } = {
    cash: 1,
    credit: 1,
    paypal: 1        
}
let OptionsKindArray = Object.keys(OptionsKind);
```

This solution will ensure that you get an error if you have any extra keys in the object, if you don't have all keys in the object and if you misspelled any keys. So basically it ensures that the duplicate data is at least always up to date.

You could even make a helper function for any union:

```
type OptionKinds = Options['kind'] //  "cash" | "paypal" | "credit"
function unionValues<T extends string>(o: Record<T, 1>) {
    return Object.keys(o) as T[];
}

let OptionKinds = unionValues<OptionKinds>({ cash: 1, paypal: 1, credit: 1 });
```

Comment: Thank you @Titian! I've tested it out and it works, but it's kind of ugly. Can the discriminator `kind` be replaced with an enum somehow? Maybe this would lead to a cleaner solution? What do you think?

Comment: @Robin you can replace the `kind` property with an enum sure. Although I don't think that will reduce duplication by a lot (you still need to define the enum speratly and use it in the interface definition also you can't be sure the enum will only contain use members (an enum member might not be used by an interface and no error would be raised). But either way can work.